# Indexing of Multidimensional Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5mDf.png)

Hello everyone,

I need to write python code to extract elements from a 2 by n bumpy array; the expected result is an 1 by n array, where the element i are randomly selected from the 1st(0,i) or 2nd(1,i) dimension.
How can I use an indices array, e.g.

```
np.array([1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1])
```

to select these elements?

e.g. the 2 by n array is:

```
array([[-1.26411167,  2.42392742, -0.43356365,  0.76705724,  3.07022449,
        -2.78946406, -2.11572523,  2.91841173, -4.80966188, -0.35692129,
         0.25358345, -1.9484944 ,  4.61027867, -2.14863628, -1.67367514,
        -0.17528167,  3.93876397, -1.54939332, -0.83699449,  0.26067597],
       [ 4.31635992, -1.72786648, -3.25743423, -4.65109192, -1.05528531,
        -2.4204626 ,  1.09321344,  2.62798824,  0.7966203 ,  2.28213528,
        -2.31325092, -0.56952984, -4.03875759,  0.74394038, -0.01667717,
        -3.4698343 ,  1.00705346, -2.17327123, -0.87080397,  4.18606604]])
```

the indices array is:

```
array([1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1])
```

The expected result(dimension=20) is:

```
np.array([4.31635992, -1.72786648, 2.42392742,...,4.18606604])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
arr[idx, np.arange(arr.shape[1])]
```

Or in the case of two rows:

```
np.where(idx==0, arr[0], arr[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have the value of `n`. According to your question, since `indexes` is of length `n`, I've used its length as `n`. I believe that you are generating the `indexes` array randomly. This code should work...

```py
indexes = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1])

values = np.array([[-1.26411167,  2.42392742, -0.43356365,  0.76705724,  3.07022449,
                    -2.78946406, -2.11572523,  2.91841173, -4.80966188, -0.35692129,
                    0.25358345, -1.9484944,  4.61027867, -2.14863628, -1.67367514,
                    -0.17528167,  3.93876397, -1.54939332, -0.83699449,  0.26067597],
                   [4.31635992, -1.72786648, -3.25743423, -4.65109192, -1.05528531,
                    -2.4204626,  1.09321344,  2.62798824,  0.7966203,  2.28213528,
                    -2.31325092, -0.56952984, -4.03875759,  0.74394038, -0.01667717,
                    -3.4698343,  1.00705346, -2.17327123, -0.87080397,  4.18606604]])

ret = []
n = len(indexes)
for x in range(n):
    ret.append(values[indexes[x]][x])

ret_np = np.array(ret)
```